# 機械学習の学習過程をグラフ化したい

Tags: python, 機械学習, tensorflow, matplotlib

現在機械学習のプログラムを作成しております。
その際に過学習をしているかの判定のために、epochごとのtrainとvalidationの関係をグラフ化したいのですが、お恥ずかしいことにプログラムの書き方がわかりません。
基本的なグラフ化のサイトには目は通しましたが、自身のプログラムへ適応させたものへの変更、また環境の都合上一度ファイルとして出力する必要がある都合上、どのようにグラフをファイルとして出力すればよいかわかりません。

コードを掲載いたしますので、具体的なコード例を用いて解決策をご教授いただければ幸いです。
普段SSHで外部のPCと接続しての作業のため、直接ターミナル等への表示ではなく、画像ファイル等の出力形態であると助かります。

```
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'                                    #警告表示の解除
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import random
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder                              #sklearnライブラリに含まれるLabelEncoderクラスをインポートしている(LabelEncoderは数値や文字列で表されたラベルを(0~ラベル種類数-1)までの数値に変換する)
from keras.utils import np_utils
import pandas as pd                                                         #データ解析を容易にするためのモジュール pdという名前でインポートしている
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer                              #Kerasライブラリに含まれるTokenizerクラスをインポートしている(Tokenizerは文章のベクトル化に必要)
from keras.utils import pad_sequences                                       #Kerasライブラリに含まれるsequenceクラスとインポートしている(sequenceは異なる長さのテンソルの末尾を0埋めして長さを揃えてくれる)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split                        #sklearnライブラリに含まれるtrain_test_splitクラスをインポートしている(train_test_splitはデータをテストと訓練に二分割する)
from keras.models import Sequential                                         #kerasライブラリに含まれるSequentialクラスをインポートしている(Sequentialは入力と出力が一つずつのニューラルネットワーク)
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, LSTM                             #kerasライブラリに含まれるDense, Embedding, LSTMクラスをインポートしている(後日調べる)
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping                                   #kerasライブラリに含まれるEarlyStoppingクラスをインポートしている(EarlyStoppingは過学習を引き起こす前に学習を止めてくれる)
from keras.layers import Dropout                                            #kerasライブラリに含まれるDropoutクラスをインポートしている(Dropoutは過学習を抑制してくれる理論は知らん)
from keras.backend import clear_session                                     #kerasライブラリに含まれるclear_sessionクラスをインポートしている(clear_sessionは識別子をリセットする)
from keras.models import Sequential                                         #kerasライブラリに含まれるSequentialクラスをインポートしている(clear_sessionは識別子をリセットする)
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout, LSTM                   #
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam                                #tensorflowライブラリに含まれるAdamクラスをインポートしている()
import optuna                                                               #
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier                     #kerasライブラリに含まれるKerasClassifierクラスをインポートしている()
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

SEED = 0
random.seed(SEED)
np.random.seed(SEED)
tf.random.set_seed(SEED)

with open("all_api_call.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content]
data = pd.DataFrame()                                                       #データフレームの作成(データフレームは表形式のデータになる)
data['feature'] = content

max_words = 800                                                             #トークン化するAPIの総数を定義
max_len = 300
X = data['feature']

"""トークン化,シーケンス番号への変換"""
#トークン化...文章を単語や文字列単語に分割すること(今回はAPI名ごとに分割)
#シーケンス番号...機械学習で扱いやすい数値
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words)                                  #Tokenizerのインスタンスを作成・num_wordsは学習させたい単語の種数を入れる
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X)                                                   #XをAPI名ごと分割し,それぞれに番号を与える(トークン化)・(例)'getasynckeystate': 1, 'ntdelayexecution': 2, 'ntclose': 3...
X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X)                                         #API名をシーケンス番号に変換する
X = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=max_len, truncating='post')                     #シーケンスの設定(maxlenはシーケンスの最大値,truncatingはmaxlen以上のシーケンスを前後どちらで切り詰めるか"post"は末尾(この場合は101回目以降がカットされる))
#print(tokenizer.word_index)
#print(X)

"""シーケンス番号とAPI名称の対応状況について(補足)"""
#トークン化の際に与えた番号とシーケンス番号が一致している
#上記対応付けを行うことでLSTMを使用して訓練を可能にしている

"""正解ラベルの読み込み"""
with open("labels.csv") as f:
    label_data = f.readlines()

"""正解ラベルの整形"""
label_data = [x.strip() for x in label_data]
data["labels"] = label_data

"""検出器の作成(今回はVirusとラベリングされている物を検出する)"""
y = data["labels"].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == "Worm.Win32.Vobfus" else 0)                #条件定義(applyはデータフレームの各行に条件を適応する)

"""訓練データとテストデータに分割"""
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.15,random_state=SEED)   #テストデータが15%,訓練が85%で分割


"""ニューラルネットワークの各層について(補足)"""
#埋め込み層...整数でエンコードされた単語ベクトルを受け取り,各単語のインデックスに対する分散表現を算出する
#分散表現...単語を低次元の実数値ベクトルで表す表現(他の方法では単語の並び順や順序を維持できない)
#LSTM層...前層からの出力である分散表現を受け取り,それをもとに訓練を行う
#出力層...予測値を出力する




"""LSTMを用いてモデル準備"""
def malware_model():
    model = Sequential()                                                    #Sequential宣言
    model.add(Embedding(max_words, 300, input_length=max_len))              #整数でエンコードされた単語(API名)ベクトルを受け取り,各単語のインデックスに対する分散表現を算出する
    model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    return model

"""モデルを有効化して訓練"""
model = malware_model()
model.summary()                                                              #モデルの要約を出力する
model.compile(                                                               #訓練に関する設定を行う
    loss='binary_crossentropy',                                              #損失関数に二値交差エントロピーを指定
    optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy']                                    #最適化アルゴリズムにAdamを指定
    )
#損失関数...正解値と算出した予測値のズレを求めるのに用いる
#二値交差エントロピー...2つの確立分布がどれくらい離れているかを表す指標
#最適化アルゴリズム...損失を0にすることを目的としたもの
#Adam...わからん
history = model.fit(                                                        #訓練の実行(history = model.fit(...)は固定)
    X_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=64,                                                          #サブセット分ける(サイズは2のn乗から決める)
    epochs=10,                                                              #学習する回数を設定(試しながら決める)
    validation_data=(X_test, y_test),                                       #検証するデータを引数として渡す
    verbose=1                                                               #結果をエポックごとのログがプログレスバーの進行状況とともに表示
    )
```

Comment: `機械学習 過程 グラフ化`といったキーワードで検索するとこんな記事が見つかりますが、例えばどんな学習のどのような状態をどのようなグラフにしたいのでしょう？ [ニューラルネットワークの学習過程を可視化してみよう](https://rightcode.co.jp/blog/information-technology/neural-network-learning-visualization), [入門 Keras (6) 学習過程の可視化と...](https://www.infiniteloop.co.jp/tech-blog/2018/02/learning-keras-06/), [【Python/keras】損失関数、評価関数の推移をグラフ化](https://algorithm.joho.info/programming/python/loss-acc-plot/), [そうだったのか！ 可視化して理解する...](https://jp.mathworks.com/content/dam/mathworks/mathworks-dot-com/company/events/webinar-cta/3261200-Presentation.pdf), [グラフってこんなにすごい！...](https://ai-scholar.tech/gnn/GNN_review)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
提示していただきました多くの資料に載っているような、epochごとのtrainとvalidationの関係をグラフにしたいです。

Comment: 回答では無く例の情報を提示しただけです。コメントにするのではなく質問記事を編集してそれらを反映し、なるべく具体化・詳細化するようにしてください。そして自分で調べたこと・試したこと等も記述してください。何もしておらずに何々したい、とか言うのは丸投げといって助言・回答する方も手を付けられません。

Comment: 課題は分割して取り組む事をおすすめします。グラフ化の前に、途中経過の値を取り出すことは出来ていますか？(確認用にまずはコンソールに出力等) / 機械学習は関係なく、用意されたデータからグラフを作成することはできていますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
途中経過の値を出力することはできていますが、グラフの作成はできていません。

Comment: 「途中経過の値を出力することはできていますが、グラフの作成はできていません。」とのことですが、簡単な折れ線グラフを描くことはできますか？

Comment: 質問を編集してコードを消しても、履歴で誰でも閲覧できるため無意味です。もし、何らかの理由でコードを削除する必要がある場合はモデレーターによる処理が必要です。[質問を取り消したいですが削除しても良いですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)をよくお読みの上、必要であればモデレーターに通報して依頼してください。

Answer (score 4):

tensorboardについては確認されましたでしょうか。
tensorflowやkerasを利用しているのであるならば、数行の修正でグラフ化が可能なので試していただければと思います。

https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/get_started?hl=ja

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard #TensorBoardをimport
import datetime

# TensorBoardのコールバックを設定
log_dir = "logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1, write_images=True)

model = xxxxx_model()  # あなたのモデル関数
model.compile(
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

# モデルの訓練中にTensorBoardコールバックを使用
history = model.fit(
    X_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=64,
    epochs=10,
    validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
    callbacks=[tensorboard_callback],  # ここにコールバックを追加
    verbose=1
)
```

その後sshで接続したターミナル上で
tensorboard --logdir logs/fit
を実行することで結果確認のためのWebサーバが立ち上がるのでそこで確認が可能です。